# array in query returns only result of first value

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I am learning about PHP, so I try to do some exercises. Now I wanted to upload an array in JSON format to my script and insert this array into the query. To test it I used three fixed values in the array. The problem I have is that only the result of the first element of the array is returned and not all three. 
I thought about fetching multiple values wrong, but with a fix condition providing more then one result it does work fine. I also thought maybe the array is passed wrong, but when I printed it from the script I got it returned completely like this:

```
(
    [0] => 141
    [1] => 145
    [2] => 54
)
```

Does anyone know where it is thought wrong?

My script:

```
<?php 
    include 'DBConfig.php';

    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    if(isset($_POST['arrayList'])){

        $JSON_Received = $_POST['arrayList'];
        $obj = json_decode($JSON_Received, true);

        $matches = implode(',', $obj);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id IN ('$matches')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $array[] = $row;
        }
    }

    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: I read it back into my app and my logcat only returns `D/TAG: Response: [{"id":"145","name":"x"}]`. It looks like that's pretty much it, but I don't have an explanation why

Comment: What does your HTML look like, and what values are you entering into the form?

Comment: You can do `$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $obj).")";` to avoid one line and if `$obj` looks like an array like this `$obj = array(0=> your_id, 1=> your_id, ...);`

Comment: @MickaelLeger For some reason it did the trick for me to follow the suggestion and include the `implode()` directly in the query! Do you have any idea why that might cause such a problem?

Comment: Your ids are INT var, so when you do `...id IN ('$matches')` you will have something that looks like this `'141, 145, 54'` (a STRING) instead of `141, 145, 54` (a list of INT). You can try to write `...id IN ($matches)` to check if it works too :)

Comment: It works as well, just like you said. I didn't think that might be the issue, so thank you very much! If you write an answer to it, I will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write `WHERE id IN ('$matches')` the result will be `WHERE id IN ('141, 145, 54')`, so you have a STRING and id are INTEGER.

Try to replace :

```
$matches = implode(',', $obj);
$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id IN ('$matches')";
```

By

```
$matches = implode(',', $obj);
$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id IN ($matches)";
```

Or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TestTable WHERE id IN (".implode(',', $obj).")";`
```

This way you will have `WHERE id IN (141, 145, 54)`, a list of INT.